# Ubuntu 14.04/15.10 - Android file access issue

Tags: 14.04, android, mtp, adb, 15.10

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04/15.10 and having trouble connecting one of my android device. 
I have tested access files from Samsung galaxy S3/ Moto G3 and Alcatel Idol3 with ubuntu.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/idol-3/general/mtp-issue-ue40-update-t3182564

Logs:

**$ lsusb**

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e3 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable Valentine
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 064e:c336 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1bbb:af2b T & A Mobile Phones 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

**$ ls -ltr /dev/bus/usb/001/006**
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 189, 5 Oct  5 21:45 /dev/bus/usb/001/006

1.I have added the device detail in  **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**,  **69-libmtp.rules** and allow_others flag in **/etc/fuse.conf** 
2. updated **libmtp version: 1.1.9**

$ sudo **mtp-detect**
libmtp version: 1.1.9

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=1bbb and PID=af2b) is a Alcatel OneTouch Idol 3 (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Alcatel: OneTouch Idol 3 (MTP) (1bbb:af2b) @ bus 1, dev 6
Attempting to connect device(s)
**PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device**
inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): No such device
libusb_open() failed!: No such file or directory
LIBMTP PANIC: Could not init USB on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.

Inspite of all these, adb is able to detect device

**$ adb devices** 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
**33a0eeaa  device**

Any idea how to fix this?